# E-book reader in iPhone: alternatives to Web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show an ebook reader with PDF format.

I have one button that displays the number of books from a Web service. These books titles are displayed in a table view. When the user clicks on a row of the table the application starts the downloading process. After completing the downloading process it shows the book information with PDF format.

I did the downloading process and it works properly. However, I used one Web view to display the book in PDF format and its performance is poor. Is there any other way of displaying a PDF document?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.veltema.jp/blog/2010/6/displaying-pdf-documents-on-ios- seems to give some great information.